# Puma error while loading library: libicuuc.so.60

Tags: upgrade, library, puma

I just did a do-realease-upgrade on ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and i'm getting an error while attempting to start a puma server for a mastodon instance.

```
bundle[8604]: [8604] ! Unable to load application: LoadError: libicuuc.so.60: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/mastodon/live/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/charlock_holmes-0.7.7/lib/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so
```

I have already reinstalled the library:

```
sudo apt-get install libicu66
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libicu66 is already the newest version (66.1-2ubuntu2.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Its been suggested I rebuild this library locally but how?

Or maybe that's not the problem? How do i procede here?